# MPLAB X - Read and Export Hex File

Tags: pic, embedded, mplab

I'm a bit stumped as to what's going on here.  I was previsouvly able to read (upload) the memory from the dspic33F and store it as a hex file.  This is the only way I can test the boot loader I'm working on right now.  In the last few hours I can no longer export the data read back to a hex file.

It appears that the programmer is connecting and reading back the file.

```
*****************************************************

Connecting to MPLAB ICD 3...
Firmware Suite Version.....01.28.72
Firmware type..............dsPIC33F/24F/24H

Target detected
Device ID Revision = 3040

The following memory area(s) will be read:
program memory: start address = 0x0, end address = 0x157ff
configuration memory
User Id Memory

Reading...
Read complete
```

But it fails to complete the "upload".

```
Connecting to programmer...
Uploading target memory...
The programmer could not be started: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Has anyone seen this issue before, if what the heck did I do to make MPLABX die on me while exporting hex files.  It's also worth nothing that the `IPE` application does not give me the option to export the hex file either.

**System Information**

- DSPIC33FJ128GP706A
- ICD3
- Windows 7 - N (x86) via Virtual Box running on OS X 7.8

**Update**

It works with my PICkit3... I'm guessing it's an issue with the ICD3??

Answer (score 1):

Try this link:
http://microchip.wikidot.com/mplab:how-to-read-a-device-and-save-the-hex-file

The description reads:

> From the main toolbar, click on the small downward pointing triangle on the right edge of the Read Device button. A drop down menu will appear. Select Read Device Memory to File…. You will be prompted for a location to save the hex file.

Here is a more general help link for MPLAB-X:
http://microchip.wikidot.com/mplab:_start

Comment: That's precisely what I'm doing.  The output copies are the result of that action.  Any idea what would cause that action to tank?

Comment: The upload completes OK with my ICD3 when reading my PIC32

Comment: It did for me as well prior to a few hours ago.  I've had random ICD3 issues like this then they go away a few days later... My workaround for the time being is to use the PICkit3 to read back the hex files and the ICD3 for debugging.

Comment: For anyone confused like me: for this button to appear, you must have an open project.